# Cocoa video playback control delegates

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I have a subclass of CAOpenGLLayer that is using, manipulating and displaying frames from an AVPlayer. I want to add playback controls to this layer, but I need to forward events from the playback controls to the AVPlayer. I have found a few examples of how to add familiar playback controls, like AVPlayerView, but all of them require me to pass in an actual movie file when what I want is just the interface that I can write custom delegates for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no built in, ready to use, playback controls that you can attach your own targets and actions to. You'll need to roll out your own UI if you are rendering things by yourself.

If you are feeling sneaky though, you might be able to add your layer (in a view) to the AVPlayerView, remove the output that AVPlayerView adds from your player item, add your own video output, and let the AVPlayerLayer take control of the playback.